# UIPageViewController with bug

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

My UIPageViewController crashes when the DataSource methods `ViewControllerAfter` and `ViewControllerBefore` returns nil (which should only mean that there's no more pages to show). It crashes with the message:

> 'The number of view controllers provided (0) doesn't match the number
>   required (1) for the requested transition'

Thanks! Please help!

My initialization code:

```
self.pageController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .pageCurl, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
                self.pageController?.dataSource = self
           //     self.pageController?.delegate = self
                self.pageController?.setViewControllers([self.controller.pages.first!], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
                self.updateControls()
                self.addChildViewController(self.pageController!)
                self.view.addSubview((self.pageController?.view)!)
                self.pageController?.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

And below my DataSource code:

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    previousIndex = self.controller.pages[self.currentPage].pageIndex!

    if previousIndex <= 0  {
        print("entrou no nil do before")
        return nil
    }

    self.previousIndex -= 1
    self.currentPage = self.previousIndex
    return self.controller.pages[previousIndex]
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    nextIndex = self.controller.pages[self.currentPage].pageIndex!

    nextIndex += 1
    if (nextIndex == self.controller.pages.count) {
        print("entrou no nil do after")
        return nil
    }
    self.currentPage = nextIndex
    return self.controller.pages[nextIndex]
}
```

Comment: you should set the initial view controller(s) using `setViewControllers` when your view loads

Comment: I initially used this method, everything works fine when paging through, the only problem is when it reaches at the end and the user tries to swipe. Or at the first viewcontroller and the user tries to swipe to go to previous page.

Answer (score 0):

Both the methods will return nil due to its behaviour. You need to handle it at your own.
This flexibility is given to put the pages in pageviewcontroller in cycle or end it on number of pages.

You need to use such code:

// MARK: - PageViewControllerDataSource

//Array of viewcontroller (pages) identifiers.

var pageTitles = [String]

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let identifier = viewController.restorationIdentifier
    var index = self.pageTitles.indexOf(identifier!)!
    print("index back = \(index)")

    if index == 0 {
        currentPageCount = -1
        nextPageCount = index
    }

    if index == 0 || index == NSNotFound {
        return nil
    }

    index -= 1
    currentPageCount = index-1
    nextPageCount = index
    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let identifier = viewController.restorationIdentifier
    var index = self.pageTitles.indexOf(identifier!)!

    if index == NSNotFound {
        return nil;
    }

    index += 1
    if index == self.pageTitles.count {
        return nil;
    }
    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)
}
```

Comment: I did handle, but when it enters on the nil case, it crashes with this message!

Comment: The error don't point to a exact line, but the last thing that is executed is the "return nil" of the DataSource methods After/Before

Comment: Use this method with my code:

func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> UIViewController? {
        if self.pageTitles.count == 0 || index >= self.pageTitles.count {
            return nil
        }
        //      self.pageControl.numberOfPages = index
      self.pageControl.numberOfPages = 4
        let identifier = self.pageTitles[index]
        let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier)
        
        return viewController
    }

Comment: I am experiencing the same bug with my (sub-classed) UIPageViewController.  Everything works, including most of the time on the last page, when one is supposed to return nil from the delegate method to prevent a forward page turn.  Tapping does nothing.  Panning does nothing.  But a quick one-finger swipe upward and to the left issues the error message, and then the app crashes.  Not good.

Comment: The bug is timing-dependent.  It goes away when I place a breakpoint inside the `pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController:` data source method, and proceed.  But the real weird thing is that the gesture is asking to move forward, and works that way on all previous pages.  But a quick flick upward and to the left (which normally is for going to the next page) is causing the `pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController:` data source method to be called, not the `pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController:` method.  Something seems very wrong inside Apple's code.